# discord.py и youtube_dl воспроизведение аудио без скачки

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, youtube

как можно воспроизвести аудио в боте при помощи библиотеки youtube_dl, но без установки самого аудио в директорию бота (из-за этой установки невозможно запустить стримы с музыкой по типу lo-fi) и если ни как нельзя, то какую библиотеку можно для этого использовать (существуют же боты по типу MEE6, Rythm, Groove, которые играют стримы спокойно и моментально, а с учётом что запуск аудио моментальный, да и боты очень популярны, то явно это происходит без скачки видео)

Comment: никакие адекватные люди не делают ботов на питоне. Для этого есть js

Comment: А что плохого в питоне для этой цели? Есть динамическая типизация, что крайне удобно при работе с переменными из команд, сам синтаксис очень простой. Чем так не устраивает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял, как решить это, достаточно в параметрах указать:

```py
YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'worstaudio/best',
               'noplaylist': 'True', 'simulate': 'True', 'preferredquality': '192', 'preferredcodec': 'mp3', 'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio'}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Делается это так:**

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
from asyncio import sleep

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'False'}
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, arg):
    global vc

    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    except:
        print('Уже подключен или не удалось подключиться')

    if vc.is_playing():
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, музыка уже проигрывается.')

    else:
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)

        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']

        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe", source = URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
                
        while vc.is_playing():
            await sleep(1)
        if not vc.is_paused():
            await vc.disconnect()
```

---

Для реализации такой команды нужен **FFMPEG** - .exe файл, необходимый для запуска звука. Этот экзешник запускается через Discord API.

Скачать его можно [здесь](https://ffmpeg.org/). Также можете [скачать архив](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/autobuild-2020-12-02-12-43/ffmpeg-N-100126-g0a5ff19643-win64-gpl.zip) *(Загрузка начнется сразу)*

В папке должно быть 3 файла: `ffmpeg.exe`, `ffplay.exe`, `ffprobe.exe`.

Запускам с явным указанием исполняемого файла `ffmpeg.exe`:

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="путь\\к\\файлу\\ffmpeg.exe", source = URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

Comment: info = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False) я правильно понял, что эта строка как раз таки предотвращает загрузку файла?

Comment: Не могли бы вы пожалуйста ещё рекомендованные параметры для FFMPEG оставить?

Comment: @MaximFilonenko, дополнил код параметрами. Да, вы все правильно поняли

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но всё же стримы этот скрип запустить не может( в вопросе я уточнил, что это одна из главных целей

Comment: raise ExtractorError('requested format not available',
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: requested format not available

Comment: @MaximFilonenko, прошу прощения, не совсем понял что вы делаете акцент именно на том, что нужно проигрывать стримы. Думал вам просто нужно понять, как проигрывать видео без скачивания. К сожалению на второй вопрос ответить не смогу, но, вероятно, это делается примерно также как и с видео. Возможно нужно где-то поменять/добавить параметры, дописать пару строчек кода. Попробуйте поискать

Comment: @denisnumb, здравствуйте у меня возникли сложности с вашим кодом, а именно конечный этап проигрывания, после загрузки, ffmpeg крашится как будто видео пытается запустить

Comment: @Igoko, мне бы код ошибки)

Comment: @denisnumb Мне бы тоже)))
Вообще никаких ошибок не выводит, но я в итоге просто добавил условность что добавить закачку, и после этого всё начало работать