# Проигрывани музыки в discord боте на python

Tags: python, бот, discord

пытаюсь научить бота проигрывать музыку на сервере, но при попытке проиграть ничего не происходит. Вот мой код

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url : str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile('song.mp3')
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove('song.mp3')
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send('wait bruh')
    voice = get(client.voice_client, guild = ctx.guild)


    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessor': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodac': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        for file in os.listdir('./'):
            if file.endwith('.mp3'):
                name = file
                os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'), after = lambda e: print(f'[log]{name} конец'))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.07
    song_name = name.rsplit('-', 2)
    await ctx.send(f'сейчас играет {song_name[0]}')
```

Помогите пожалуйста найти проблему. Всем заранее спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации такой команды нужен **FFMPEG** - .exe файл, необходимый для запуска звука. Этот экзешник запускается через Discord API.

Скачать его можно [здесь](https://ffmpeg.org/). Также можете [скачать архив](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/autobuild-2020-12-02-12-43/ffmpeg-N-100126-g0a5ff19643-win64-gpl.zip) *(Загрузка начнется сразу)*

В папке должно быть 3 файла: `ffmpeg.exe`, `ffplay.exe`, `ffprobe.exe`.

Запускам с явным указанием исполняемого файла `ffmpeg.exe`:

```
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="путь\\к\\файлу\\ffmpeg.exe", source = 'song.mp3', **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

---

Полноценный код можете найти [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214921/discord-py-%D0%B8-youtube-dl-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8/1214936#1214936)